# Strange Typecasting errors

Tags: c, serialization, casting

So, I have this function, and I am getting some really weird errors that I can't figure out.

```
void serialize_helper(huff *h, bits *history, char** a)
{
  switch (h->tag) {
  case LEAF:
    char letter = h->h.leaf.c;
    int arraynum = (int)letter;
    a[arraynum] = bits_show(history);
    putchar('\n');
    return;
  case NODE:
    /* traverse left subtree */
    bits_putlast('0',history);
    serialize_helper(h->h.node.lsub,history, a);
    bits_remove_last(history);
    /* traverse right subtree */
    bits_putlast('1',history);
    serialize_helper(h->h.node.rsub,history, a);
    bits_remove_last(history);
    return;
  default:
    fprintf(stderr,"main.serialize_helper: bad tag\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

I am getting this error for a simple variable definition (from char letter = ...;):

"huffenc.c:18: error: expected expression before ‘char’"

Furthermore, the compiler is acting like my declaration of "letter" does not exist:
"huffenc.c:19: error: ‘letter’ undeclared (first use in this function)"

Comment: Why am I not allowed to declare a variable there? I thought that was allowed...

Comment: Are you compiling in C89 mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define a variable in a `switch` directly after a `case` you need to have a block, e.g.

```
  case LEAF: {
    char letter = h->h.leaf.c;
    int arraynum = (int)letter;
    a[arraynum] = bits_show(history);
    putchar('\n');
    return;
  }
```

---

EDIT: The reason is simply that a label can only be followed by a statement, and a declaration or initialisation isn't a statement, while a block (i.e. compound statement) is.